# Test Complete script does not get the object of my application on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: testcomplete

I wrote a script using Test Complete 6.0 to automate my application. Test Complete does not get the object of my application.

For example: `Sys["Application name"]` returns with "object not found". I tried to find what are the EXE running under `sys` through the script. I found my application is not there under `sys` even though my application is running in machine.

This problem is occuring only in one Windows 7 machine. On other Windows 7 and XP machines, my scripts are working fine.

Comment: Did you copy the files required to the path they have to be in ?

Comment: so you're telling us "something works on one machine but not on another"? That's not helpful. Tells us what you're doing different and why you are expecting it to do the same

Comment: Hi shivan:  I have copied all the required files in respective location. Thanks you

Comment: Hi stefen thanks for your reply.. Following are the differnce: 1. Both the PC are win 7 64 bit. 2. PC where my code works has test complete and other has test execute..

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to your application in the following way:
**Sys.Process("Process of your tested app")**

The fact that you cannot see the process of your tested applicaion in TestComplete may be related to [the Object Browser toolbar commands](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29276/). Make sure that the **Show All User Processes** option is enabled.

Comment: @ Tanya thanks for your reply. I am also using the same way you mentioned. but its not working. The pc where its not working does not have test complete it has only test execute.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the application under test is running as Administrator while TestExecute does not. This makes the tool unable to access the application process. Run TestExecute as Administrator (right-click TestExecute executable and select 'Run as administrator') and check whether this helps.

BTW, TestComplete/TestExecute 6 does not support Windows 7 officially.